# Anaconda environment with a python specific

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

How to create Anaconda environment with a python specific version.

being more specific, python 3.6.8 (32 bit)

Comment: `conda create -n "myenv" python=3.6.8` will create environment exactly as per your need

Comment: Yes, but the 64-bit version would be installed, in this case it is something very specific and the 32bit version would have to be selected, is there any way to include this information in the creation of the environment?